# Denied entry to Japan (no visa) but Airline let me board

Tags: visas, compensation, denial-of-entry, etihad, travel-insurance-claim

So I had a trip planned to Tokyo, Japan for about 8 days.

I'm a British Citizen and unfortunately and also very stupidly didn't realise I needed a Visa to enter the country. I was positive that nothing was required through reading through the UK Govt site, however reading it now it does state that a Visa is required which I take full accountability for.

My issue is that the Airline I booked with (Etihad) failed to ask me for this at both the UK and Abu Dhabi where I had a layover and let me board both Aircrafts.

What's the best way if possible for me to go ahead and get a full refund for my troubles or at the bare minimum get my trip rebooked for a future date.

I also do have travel insurance.

Comment: Very unlikely to succeed, but it wouldn't hurt to try to apply for the visa there.  Being of course fully honest about your mistake.  Maybe even a bit of obsequiousness.  But don't offer a bribe—has the potential to help with a dishonest one but the potential for big trouble with an honest official.  (And the dishonest one might see it as a signal they could get even more out of you!)

Comment: I did ask them when I was there and immediately was shut down. It was required upon arrival, I was very honest about the situation and came across very genuine. I'm just more annoyed about the airline and basically had travelled across the whole globe due to an incompetent airline. I just feel like within 2 countries someone should have stopped me or at the very least made me  aware.

Comment: @Yas Yes. Usually airline catches these types of things. They made a mistake and they paid for it by bearing cost to repatriate you and pay the fine imposed by Japan.

Comment: It’s unlikely you will get a refund: the airline provided you with exactly what it promised: transport to your destination.   The airline is not responsible for your entry in Japan and never promised their airfare would guarantee entry.

Comment: You "take full accountability" but want a "full refund"?

Comment: Not only will they not give you anything, it's somewhat likely that *they* will seek a refund from *you* (for the cost of flying you home and/or for the fine they paid to Japan for incorrectly flying you there).

Comment: @Kevin In a situation like this they normally take the return ticket as payment for flying you home.  However, they might seek to recover any fine they paid.

Answer (score 35):

As a general practice, making sure you are admissible in destination country is your responsibility. Airlines usually verify closely, as they have to transport you back to your origin (or your home country) and may have to pay a fine, as they allowed passenger without proper documents. They obviously made a mistake here. But, its ultimately your responsibility and **airline does not owe you anything**.

For travel insurance, it can vary. But not securing proper documents is still your problem and a situation that's totally within your control. Some insurance may accept a claim, but mostly your are out of luck on this.

Chalk it up as a learning opportunity and make sure you double check the visa requirements and documents needed for admission, even before booking the ticket.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the second question is could I do anything about the treatment I received at all? For the first time in my life I was detained and was made to feel like an absolute criminal. Etihad also held onto my passport for both flights until I arrived in the UK making me feel like an actual criminal. I promise i'm not asking for pity party here but I do believe I was treated unjustly.

Comment: @Yas You are trying to blame the airline here for your mistake and wrongdoing. Being detained and deported under surveillance is a perfectly normal and regular reaction if you try to seek entry to a country without the proper credentials. The Japanese government has not done you anything wrong and neither has the airline. The airline failed to do their obligation towards the Japenese government (make sure that you are entitled to enter Japan to allow you to board) and they have probably been fined for that mistake. They did not do anything wrong to you.

Comment: @Yas This is just a fact of the way people are treated when they are denied entry. Our (UK) government does exactly the same. It's an upsetting experience but ultimately no one else is at financial fault for it.

Comment: Actually, not only does the airline owe the passenger nothing, many airlines can even reclaim from the passenger any fines they had to pay and all associated costs (including the return flight, which is not the flight originally booked). The carrier’s T&Cs will tell you that.

Comment: @jcaron forget T&Cs, its part of the ICAO rules, so all airlines can recover their transportation costs for removing inadmissible persons - https://www.icao.int/WACAF/Documents/Meetings/2018/FAL-IMPLEMENTATION/an09_cons.pdf Chapter 5, paragraph 5.10

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139728/discussion-between-moo-and-tor-einar-jarnbjo).

Comment: *For the first time in my life I was detained and was made to feel like an absolute criminal...*  I am truly sorry you endured that horrible experience, which I have also experienced multiple times (for other reasons).  The silver lining, hopefully, is that by experiencing this pain firsthand, you will develop even more compassion for people who deal with this type of pain on a daily basis.

Comment: @Moo [What's the point of indemnity forms if the ICAO rules state the airlines can recover the costs for removing inadmissible persons?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/176799/1810)

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket - There are people who are denied entry to countries on a daily basis?

Comment: @Obie2.0 I was referring to the millions of human beings who are regularly subjugated as the victims of prejudice and hate.  I am not stating that this person was the victim of an act of prejudice or hate in this situation, rather that the silver lining of such experiences may help people develop compassion for those who deal with this type of pain on a daily basis.  Being treated like a criminal when you are not one is a painful and often traumatic experience.  I have much first-hand experience in this regard since early childhood.